# gcov - how to reset the coverage statistics in the C/C++ code

Tags: googletest, gcov

This question is related to [googletest - command line option to execute "the first, the second, etc"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72777177/googletest-command-line-option-to-execute-the-first-the-second-etc)

I want to be able to attribute given coverage results to each `googletest` test case.

**QUESTION**
In my C++ code, is it possible to reset the statistics?

Every time a test-case is done executing, I would save the accumulated `gcov` statistics and reset them.

Answer (score 0):

From within your C++ code you could try it with `__gcov_dump` and `__gcov_reset`. They are mentioned in the [GNU documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-and-Optimization.html#Gcov-and-Optimization) although there is surprisingly limited info on them.

Below is a C++ program `main.cpp` that calls both.

```
  1 #include <iostream>                                                             
  2 #include <signal.h>                                                             
  3                                                                                 
  4 extern "C" void __gcov_dump(void);                                              
  5 extern "C" void __gcov_reset(void);                                             
  6                                                                                 
  7                                                                                 
  8 static void handler(int signum)                                                 
  9 {                                                                               
 10     std::cout<<std::endl<<"Signal "<<signum<<" received!"<<std::endl;           
 11     __gcov_dump(); // Dump coverage upon interupt                               
 12     std::cout<<"Coverage data dumped!"<<std::endl;                              
 13     exit(0);                                                                    
 14 }                                                                               
 15                                                                                 
 16                                                                                 
 17 int main()                                                                      
 18 {                                                                               
 19     // Initialize signal handling                                               
 20     struct sigaction sa;                                                        
 21                                                                                 
 22     sa.sa_handler = handler;                                                    
 23     sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);                                                   
 24     sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;                                                   
 25                                                                                 
 26     if (sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL) == -1)                                     
 27         std::cerr<<"ERROR: Could not register handler"<<std::endl;              
 28                                                                                 
 29     // Main loop                                                                
 30     while(true) {                                                               
 31         int n;                                                                  
 32         std::cout<<"Type a number: ";                                           
 33         std::cin>>n;                                                            
 34                                                                                 
 35         if (n % 2 == 0) {                                                       
 36             std::cout<<"Your number is even!"<<std::endl;                       
 37         }                                                                       
 38         else {                                                                  
 39             std::cout<<"Your number is odd!"<<std::endl;                        
 40         }                                                                       
 41         __gcov_reset(); // Reset coverage at the end of every iteration         
 42     }                                                                           
 43 }
```

If I compile it with `g++ main.cpp --coverage -O0`  and then run it as follows:

```
gomfy:gcov$ ./a.out
Type a number: 1
Your number is odd!
Type a number: 2
Your number is even!
Type a number: 3
Your number is odd!
Type a number: 4
Your number is even!
Type a number: ^C
Signal 2 received!
Coverage data dumped!
```

And then call [gcovr](https://gcovr.com/en/stable/) in the build directory, I get:

```
gomfy:gcov$ gcovr
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           GCC Code Coverage Report
Directory: .
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File                                       Lines    Exec  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
main.cpp                                      18       6    33%   12-13,17,22-24,26-27,35-36,39,41
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                         18       6    33%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This shows that the coverage has been successfully reset at the end of the while loop.